# Porting Android's Java VM to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android, jvm

Does anyone know of any existing projects that aim to port Android's Java VM over to the iPhone? From what I understand, this wouldn't be too out of reach and would certainly make for some exciting developments.

**Edit**: I should point out that I am aware this will not happen using the official iPhone SDK. However, a jailbroken platform would remove any Apple-imposed roadblocks. I imagine most that would be interested in integrating Android into the iPhone would also be the demographic that would typically have a jailbroken iphone.

Comment: Based on [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/08/03/14/Suns-plan-for-Java-on-iPhone-could-hit-roadblock_1.html), that doesn't seem likely as the iPhone SDK agreement wouldn't allow a program that downloads/runs other programs.

Comment: And now Apple is allowing alternative development tools for iOS? If Flash is allowed, then i assume Java would be. Here's hoping for iDalvik real soon now ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't currently an effort to port [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine) to iPhone because [Google hasn't released the source yet](http://code.google.com/android/roadmap.html).  As soon as the source is released (assuming all of it will be) I would think this will happen.  It's also likely to be seen on other homebrew platforms such as PSP, [Pandora](http://openpandora.org/), [openmoko](http://www.openmoko.com/), etc.

Comment: Any update on Google releasing Dalvik's source? The link in the answer doesn't work and a quick google search didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Android Dalvik run on iOS:

The "In the box" open source project show on their website (www.in-the-box.org) for the first time and as a first step of their open source project a Android Dalvik VM running on iOS. (No need to jailbreak).

"In the box" is an open source project create to provide a porting of Gingerbread Android runtime on top of iOS. It enables Android application developers to execute their Android application on iOS.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: You might want to disclaim that you're associated with this project, based on the link in your profile.

Comment: Yes you are right, i m closely linked to this open source project and it s not a secret and think that I m replying to the original question. For memory the question was :"Does anyone know of any existing projects that aim to port Android's Java VM over to the iPhone?". That's exactly what we're trying to do with In-the-box. Sorry if you feel like we are lobbying

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's perfectly fine to suggest your own open source project as a solution to a problem.  We do see people astroturfing for their products here, so people can get a little itchy with the spam flags if you don't fully disclose that you're with the project in question.  In fact, people might take your answers more seriously if you state that you're one of the developers of said project.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there are no existing projects aiming to port Dalvik (the Android VM, which is not *really* a Java VM since it doesn't execute Java bytecode) to the iPhone. There is, however, at least one "real" Java VM available for the iPhone. You can find it in Cydia on jailbroken phones.

The issue with these projects is that Apple doesn't allow third-party apps to execute code, so Java VMs can only run on jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iPhone is a closed system.  They control what is deployed from the OS to the applications.  They have said they have no intention of supporting a JVM.  This would have to be a rogue application outside of that control and therefore not very appealing to the masses.

Answer (score -8):

To be useful you'd also have to port the connection to Google's App Store.  Yeah, Apple's gonna allow that.  We're much more likely to see some iPhone-emulation tools for the Android.

Comment: I don't think what Apple will/won't allow is really of any consequence. It might stop some developers, but I imagine many are aware and would have no problem pursuing the jailbreak route.

Comment: Furthermore, iPhone emulation is a massive undertaking unless you pirate all of Apple's libraries that implement the iPhone operating system and UI.